# How to get value of select in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a value from a select and if it is bad selection you get an error. For example:

```
<select name = "dogs" id = "dogs">                  
<option value="dog1">Dog 1</option>                 
<option value="dog2">Dog 2</option>
<option value="cat1">Cat 1</option>
</select>
```

If someone selected cat1, they would get an error.

```
var x = document.getElementById("dogs");
var dogInspector = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;

if(document.forms['form1'].dogInspector.value === "cat1"){
   document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "No cats allowed!";
   return false;
}
```

I'm unsure why this isn't working? Is it the if statement?

Comment: Have you tried using `x.value`? I think you should be able to access the selected value this way.

Comment: What are you expecting `document.forms['form1'].dogInspector.value` to be? Does the form have an element with `name="dogInspector"`?

Comment: I think you mean `document.forms['form1'][dogInspector]`

Comment: I was expecting document.forms['form1'].dogInspector.value to be "cat1", the option that was selected from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x.value`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("dogs");
x.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
  if(x.value === "cat1"){
     alert("No cats allowed!");
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="dogs" id="dogs">                  
  <option value="dog1">Dog 1</option>                 
  <option value="dog2">Dog 2</option>
  <option value="cat1">Cat 1</option>
</select>
```